# uiscrollview subclass to detect touch not working

Tags: ios4

i used this code to detect touch on an uiscrollview who is on top of uiview

subclass

.h file

```
@interface AppScrollView : UIScrollView 
{
}

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "AppScrollView.h"

@implementation AppScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
  return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{   
  // If not dragging, send event to next responder
  if (!self.dragging) 
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
  else
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

@end
```

and then on another class i added

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AppScrollView;

@interface SomeClass : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
  AppScrollView *scrollView;
  ...
}

@end

#import "AppScrollView.h"

@implementation SomeClass

...

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{
  // Process the single tap here
  ...
}

...

@end
```

i used also `scroll1.delegate=self;` but nothing happens!!!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you creating a subclass only to detect a touch?

Comment: yes this is why i implemented the subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Gesture Recognizers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html). Specifically [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).